# Creating a loop to generate mouseover functions

Tags: image, function, loops, mouseover

I've got a list of mouseOver functions, which for other pages will be much longer, so I'm looking for a way to generate the mouseOver functions in a loop.

Here's a small list of 5 functions in an example, by putting that in a single loop functions I should be able to understand how to expand it to more.

```
function mouseOver1()
{
    document.pic.src ="img1.jpg"
}

function mouseOver2()
{
    document.pic.src ="img2.jpg"
}

function mouseOver3()
{
    document.pic.src ="img3.jpg"
}

function mouseOver4()
{
    document.pic.src ="img4.jpg"
}

function mouseOver5()
{
    document.pic.src ="img5.jpg"
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: To be honest my knowledge of JS is so bad that I've only tried things that I could understand or seemed like logic to me. It's probably a rediculous attempt but I tried generating the functions the same way I generate the series of pictures in a marquee, with a for-loop where variable i is both the img number and the function number. Apperently you can't write javascript code the same way as you write html code.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: Try creating a `mouseOver` method that accepts `i` as an argument.

Comment: I've been searching for a while, still havent found how I should do that. If it's something I'd need to understand allready, I'll need a course of beginners Javascript first, I'm stuck here.

I tried this before but it doesnt do anything:
    for (i=1;i<6;i++;) {
    function (mouseOver+i()
    {
    document.pic.src="img"+i+".jpg";
    })
    }

Like I said, my knowledge of JS might be too low for this.

Comment: Is the `document.pic.src` part identical in all of them? Is the only thing that is different is the number in the image name?

Comment: Yes @fredsbend, but the answer Matt Grande gave me works perfect for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moving discussion from comments)

You don't want to create five different methods. You want one method that can handle all of your situations.

```
function mouseOver(i) {
    document.pic.src="img" + i + ".jpg";
}
```

And where before you would've called it like this:

```
mouseOver1();
```

You now call it like this:

```
mouseOver(1);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: wow it actually was that simple, this works perfect! I feel kinda stupid but at least I learned something here, thanks a million!

Comment: done, sorry still new to this site, thanks again!